# Join an array to every row in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and an array as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(0,5), 'y' : range(1,6)})
s = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I would like to attach the array to every row of the data frame, such that I got a data frame as follows:

[image]

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just plain assignment:

```
# replace the first `s` with your desired column names
df[s] = [s]*len(df)
```

Comment: Interestingly, `df[s] = s` gives the intended results.

Comment: @Ch3steR I swear I tried both `df[s] =s` and `df.loc[:, s] = s` and got an error before resolving to this. Now both works...

Comment: I don't know where I got this but I thought assigning to a numpy array would raise some error. So, I tried `df.loc[:, s] = s.tolist()` it worked and just for the fun of it I tried `df[s] = s` which worked as well.

Comment: If you don't mind you can add `df[s] = s` to your answer as an alternate solution.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in s:
    df[i] = i
```

Output:

```
   x  y  a  b  c
0  0  1  a  b  c
1  1  2  a  b  c
2  2  3  a  b  c
3  3  4  a  b  c
4  4  5  a  b  c
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas.concat`:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(s).T], axis=1).ffill()
```

output:

```
   x  y  0  1  2
0  0  1  a  b  c
1  1  2  a  b  c
2  2  3  a  b  c
3  3  4  a  b  c
4  4  5  a  b  c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) here.

```
df.loc[:, s] = s

print(df)

   x  y  a  b  c
0  0  1  a  b  c
1  1  2  a  b  c
2  2  3  a  b  c
3  3  4  a  b  c
4  4  5  a  b  c
```